# Multiple Reports with one call/in one PDF

Tags: jasper-reports

I am just new with Jasper Reports and build two reports like:
First one: Gets as Parameter an Employee-Id and displays all employee details.
Second one: Gets as Parameter a Salery-Id and displays all salery details for a month.

Now I am trying to generate a Report that has as first page the employee details and than all salery reports for all month the employee has worked (and got money...).

So I set "Summary on a new page" to my employee report and add salery report as subreport in summery band.
But how do I call the salery report several times? I assume, I have to get all salery-Ids for the employee and pass them to salery report, but how?

Or am I completely on the woodway to do so?!

Comment: At which platform you are working? java or something else..

Comment: Currently I am using Jaspersoft Studio 5.5.

Comment: Right now my working-steps would be:
1.) I create Employee-Report.
2.) I get all Monthly-Salery-Ids from Database (SELECT id FROM salery WHERE employee_Id = $P{EMPLOYEE_ID})
3.) I create a Monthly-Salery-Report for each id from Step2.
4.) I use another tool to merge all generated reports.

I think, there must be an easier way...